# API call in MVC does not return the data when run the project from Index code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an Employee controller and from Index view I'm making a call to API to get some data from database.

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
        public EmployeeController()
        {
            this.employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();
        }
        public List<Employee> Get()
        {
            return employeeRepository.GetAllEmployee().ToList();

        }
    }
```

And the Index code is as follows:

```
<div id="body">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="employees">                
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

@section scripts
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('api/employee', function (employeesJsonPayload) {
                $(employeesJsonPayload).each(function (i, item) {
                    $('#employees').append('<tr><td>' + item.Id + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + item.Name + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + item.Location + '</td></tr>')
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

When I run the project from Controller it works fine and returns the data to view but when I run the project from `Index.cshtml` it doesn't return any data. What is going on here? Can some please enlighten me.

Comment: well normally you have a model which gets pased from the controller to the view. This model than can be used direcly in the View.  Or is there any reason u use a script? [msdn](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view)

Comment: Seems like a stupid question but, did you debug your API code, to make sure data is returned?

Comment: @jpgrassi yeah, It seems really stupid problem when I faced it, but when I modify something in `index.cshtml` and directly hit F5 then it does not show any data but on the other hand when I modify `index` and goto `controller` and hit F5 then it shows the proper data. I have no idea why is that happening.

Comment: @C0dingJammer, Used script to make API call. I followed [Build RESTful API's with ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Just be clear, I said stupid question for my own question to you :). Looking to your code now, you are calling your API in the "ready" event. I suspect that it is being called only once. Why don't you stop doing this via javascript and just do it in the Index action of your controller?

Comment: @jpgrassi, yeah, data is returned as I mentioned in question itself but only when I run the project via `Controller`

Comment: @jpgrassi, thanks for the alternative you mentioned but is there any specific reason for this behavior?

Comment: I only suspect that your javascript is only fired once, could you confirm if that is what's really happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something's wrong with JS part. Open web console, reload index page and watch for errors, that could give a hint. Also look at network tab and study XHR requests (if there are any).

Check where you put that section scripts, maybe it's placed before you load jQuery?

Also this jQuery's `$(document).ready` acts really weird sometimes and the code does not get fired at all. Try to put `console.log('document loaded')` as the first line in that part to check whether the code gets ever called. It's hard sometimes to understand why exactly it is so, therefore, if it doesn't get invoked, try

```
window.onload = function(){
 $.getJSON('api/employee', function (employeesJsonPayload) {
                $(employeesJsonPayload).each(function (i, item) {
                    $('#employees').append('<tr><td>' + item.Id + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + item.Name + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + item.Location + '</td></tr>')
                });
            });
}
```

EDIT: Turned out a wrong api call: the script requested `home/api/employee` instead of `api/employee`

Comment: Sorry It's the same not returning any data from backend and FYI it does it the script as added an alert to the js and it being htting

Comment: thanks - post analysis i found its calling `home/api/employee` instead of `api/employee`. looks like a routing issue